# Installed tensorflow, but running programs gives error that says "no module named tensorflow.python"

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am working on a Windows device and I am new to ML. I installed tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow` and it ran for a bit, and at last showed this:

```
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-intel, tensorflow
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\maste_0c98yk4\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\com_github_grpc_grpc\\src\\core\\ext\\filters\\client_channel\\health\\health_check_client.h'
```

Then I looked up the tensorflow docs and it says gpu support ran out with version 2.11 but that's not an issue because I don't have a good gpu anyways but even installing `tensorflow-cpu` wouldn't work.

- pip version is 23.1.2
- Python version is 3.11

Comment: Can you include the full output of `pip install`?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a long paths issue with Windows. Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, MAX_PATH limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior.

Open the Group Policy Editor by running gpedit.msc in the command prompt. Go to `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem`. Find the Enable Win32 long paths policy and enable it.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later

Comment: Am running windows 11 home edition, so no group policy editor. Here's what I have done though: Installed anaconda, created an environment on it and there installed tensorflow and it worked with no issues. It is however hectic switching between environments in vscode since the conda environment's python version is old. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can modify the registry key directly by using PowerShell as admin and running the command : `New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force`